# solaris + metadb + hard drive mirroring

Tags: raid, solaris, mirror

I have Solaris machine
With two disks (the disks defined as RAID 1 (mirror configuration )
actually when I pull out one disk the second disk will be active

The problem is that when I run metadb on my Solaris  machine I see only one disk - /dev/dsk/c1t0d0s7 in place to see two see two disks ?

Mirroring of the initial hard drive is taken place to the second hard drive.remark - 
However – if the first hard drive fails – the mirroring is useless since the replica information is not added for the second hard drive.

please advice how to add the second disk ?

```
    [root@solaris1a /]# metadb
    flags           first blk       block count
    a m  p  luo        16              8192            /dev/dsk/c1t0d0s7
    a    p  luo        8208            8192            /dev/dsk/c1t0d0s7
    a    p  luo        16400           8192            /dev/dsk/c1t0d0s7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell metadb explicitly what slices to use for its meta data. This

```
# metadb -a -c 2 c1t1d0s7
```

will place two more copies of the metadb into slice */dev/dsk/c1t1d0s7*.